# Could not run Script properly on host after connecting

Tags: linux, shell, ssh

I am new to linux scripting. Please help. I searched on below a lot but was not able to find appropriate answer :

I am trying to make a script which I will later schedule as cronjob, so that it keeps running on backend and stores results in a file say test.txt

Main points of script are below :

1. it connects to a host through ssh and then runs a few commands on that host and saves the results in a file.The script is connecting to host successfully but not running commands automatically on host. Script is as below :

```
 #!/usr/bin/expect
    spawn ssh guest@host-ip
    expect "host pwd"
    send "pass123\r"
    interact
    cd /home/target/ ...                           /* goes to some specific path*/
    ./Script.sh >> test.txt                        /* runs a script on host and saves the result*/
    exit
```

So I updated my script according to one of the answer .. as below -

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn ssh aspen
expect "password: "    
send "PASSWORD\r"    
expect "$ "    
send "/bin/sh /home/target/Script.sh >>test.txt"    
expect "$ "    
send "exit\r"
```

But when I run this script it doesn't save complete output on test.txt Second thing is I want this output file on my own system not on host . Any help will be appreciable.

Comment: I think you need to remove the "interact" and just `send` the remaining commands.

Answer (score 2):

Run the script below on your end. It will ssh into aspin as the user `user`. The output of the whole ssh session including the output of /home/target/Script.sh will be appended to the local file test.txt Additionally, grep strips out expect being prompted for the password.

```
#!/bin/bash

{
/usr/bin/expect  <<- EOF
    spawn ssh user@aspin "/home/target/Script.sh"
    expect "password:"
    send "PASSWORD\r"
    expect eof
EOF
} |grep -v  "user@apsin's password:">>  test.txt
```

Alternatively, and arguably much safer, as well as much simpler for programmers, you should do away with expect and log into aspin with ssh using a cryptographic key that proves who you are without being prompted for a password.

Step by step process:

```
$ ssh-keygen
```

You will be prompted for a passphrase. If you want to do away with using expect, you could use an empty passphrase. Your next step is to copy your public key to user@aspin:~/.ssh/ so that you can use your private key to prove yourself.

```
$ ssh-copy-id  user@aspin
```

You should now be able to log in without being asked your password. Below is how your local script might look if your using rsa key based authentication and no passphrase

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh user@aspin "/home/target/Script.sh" >>  test.txt
```

For further info on expect and remote logins check out: [When to use Expect scripting and when to avoid it.](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/brian/entry/when_to_use_expect_scripting_and_when_to_avoid_it10?lang=en)

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

spawn ssh aspen

expect "password: "

send "PASSWORD\r"

expect "$ "

send "/bin/sh /home/target/Script.sh >>test.txt"

expect "$ "

send "exit\r"
```

Comment: thanx! it works . But I still have some issues . 1.) it does not save complete output on test.txt  2.) This test.txt is made on host & I want it on my own System.. Please help !!

Comment: @prashant: Just move the redirection outside. But the whole thing is wrong. Ssh does not accept passwords from script to discourage the insecure practice of storing passwords in scripts. Don't do it.

Answer (score 1):

Please, don't use expect with ssh. Especially don't use it to give the password.

Whenever you need scripted ssh session, you should use [public key authentication](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys). Then you can send the commands directly to ssh's standard input or pass them as argument. Or, even better, define the command on the *server*, via the `command` option in `.ssh/authorized_keys`, which is more secure, because even if somebody gets hold of the key (which can't be protected with passphrase), they won't be able to run any other commands.

Comment: I have often wondered about the benefit of a passphrase. If you use one, then your automated remote login scripts require using expect. And, if an attacker could read your ~/.ssh/id_rsa private key, they could read your expect scripts or likely install key stroke loggers.

Comment: @KeithReynolds: Ssh does not accept either passwords or key passphrases from scripts. Scripts should use single-purpose passprhaseless keys, preferably restricted on the server side (usually via command). Passphrase is appropriate for keys used interactively, where public key authentication is still safer than password one.

Comment: Expect is its own limited scripting language. Regarding using a passphrase or password, notice that I said  "If you use one, then your automated remote login scripts require using expect." Thus if you need expect to script remote logins using ssh with a password or passphrase, implicit is the fact that ssh wont accept passphrase or password from bash.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

if {[llength $argv] != 5} {

puts "usage: ssh.exp username password server port program"

exit 1

}

set username [lrange $argv 0 0]

set password [lrange $argv 1 1]

set server [lrange $argv 2 2]

set port [lrange $argv 3 3]

set program [lrange $argv 4 4]

set timeout 60

spawn ssh -p $port $username@$server $program

match_max 100000

expect "*?assword:*"

send -- "$password\r"

send -- "\r"

expect eof
```

**Run as :**

```
./ssh.exp root toor localhost 22  ./home/target/Script.sh >>test.txt
```